# Aspectj and android project

Tags: android, aop, aspectj

How can I intercept without converting my android project to Aspect j ?

```
aspect Trace {

pointcut methodCalls(): 
  execution(* com.test..*(..))&& !within(com.test.Trace);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You want to use AspectJ without using AspectJ? I do not understand. Please edit the question and clarify.

Comment: i want to use Aspectj without install plugin in eclipse

Comment: you have to use at least one building tool to weave such aspect modules. Perhaps, you may need to use Maven or directly ajc which could solve your purpose, with this regard, you don't need to use the AJDT in your eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really have no idea why you are unwilling to install AJDT (AspectJ Development Tools) in Eclipse because it makes life so much easier during aspect development and debugging, but be it as it might, you can write your aspects in any text editor and compile/weave them via [Ajc (AspectJ Compiler)](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ajc-ref.html). If you are not in software development stone age and have a Maven build, there is the excellent [AspectJ Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/) for automating your build.

Answer (score 0):

It is really impossible to intercept without converting Android project to AspectJ provided you write your own logs in each method of your Android Project and monitor it later.